# How to determine locale per mime 1.0 email message

Tags: localization, smtp, mime-types, mime

Is it possible to determine the locale (language) of an email message (MIME 1.0)?  The particular use case I'm working on is trying to distinguish certain locales per email then translate accordingly per a custom smtp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the charset value of the Content-Type header. Unless it's UTF-8, you can usually get an idea of the language the email was composed in.

Does that help?

Comment: thx for the reply. what other values would be present?  The only think that I have seen for Content_Type="multipart/alternative; or Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7b6dd0b4e9d04104ef8f7021.  So there is no utf8 but these two messages were actually en_US.

Comment: Just saw your comment.  That content-type header is saying your message is composed of alternative parts. You need to drill down 1 more level, and look at the content-type of the sub parts.

Comment: Popular character sets like US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1 is used for a wide variety of languages, including many for which they are not actually suitable (for historical reasons, or because the user wasn't able -- or allowed! -- to configure it properly). Similarly, recent versions of Exchange seem to put in an X-Accept-Language: header which reflects the server's configuration, not the user's preference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way, but for some scenarios, the precision of a language guesser like `libtextcat` is sufficient.

If you go down this route, notice that `libtextcat` ships with a very crude collection of language models which are basically just a proof of concept. LibreOffice maintains a fork `libexttextcat` which has proper language models, but only for Unicode. Creating your own language models isn't very hard, either.